# Need advise to link a cck field with several values to another cck field

Tags: entities

I am going to try to explain what I need to do. I have a content type called Goals. This content type has a cck text field. This field can has several values in order to write a goal in each value of the field.

What I want is when a user write a new goal (each goal is a value in the same cck field), he has a list tex field to point if he completed the goal.

How can i do this? What is the best option I have?

After I would like to create I view to show the goals completed and incompleted, so the goal and completed-incompleted must be linked in certain way.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement I think you have need to create something like project & the task related to the project. I have done something like this.

For this you will have to create a main content type to hold the project, which will have TITLE & BODY without any other fields.

Create one another content type with reference to first content type. User can add as many task as needed below the first content if permission is given. Add a field named STATUS in 2nd content type, which will hold this COMPLETED or NOT-COMPLETED status of the task.

You can make views of it below the first content type by adding relation between first & second content type & adding the fields by help of the relation.

Let me know if it works in your scenario..

Comment: Thank you, finally I did it with this field collection module. You can try it

Comment: @Santinuro - Congrats..but I don't need it as I am running with my own solution very efficiently..